# Travis: We couldn't find the repository

Tags: github, travis-ci

I added a new Github Repo. Travis shows me this page:
[image]

All other repos are listed.

Is there a waiting time, did I miss something or do I have to create an issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution was to log out and log in again on https://travis-ci.org.